# javascript Form Submitting location

Tags: javascript

After the user submits a form, how do I make it so that the user will get a form back on their browser?

I know I need to use location.search

```
<form id="survey" name="survey">
    First Name
    <input type="text" id="first" name="first" required/><br><br>

    Last Name
    <input type="text" id="last" name ="last" required /><br><br>

    # of Attendees
    <input type="number" id="attend" name="attend" required /><br><br>

    Email Address
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required /><br><br>

    Time of Arrival
    <input type="text" id="time" name="time" required /> <br><br>

    Spend the Night
    <select id="night" name="night">
        <option value=" "> </option>
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" onclick="enter()"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Could you, please, elaborate your question a bit more?